# mostrar campo especifico del ultimo registro ingresado en laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla que tiene entre sus campos un campo numérico. Necesito recuperar en mi vista el ultimo registro ingresado y en concreto ese campo numérico para mostrarlo en un input text.
Estoy usando en mi controlador este código:

```
$id_asignacion = AsignacionMaterial::select('num_guia_despacho')->latest()->get();//retornar el ultimo id de asignacion registrado
```

En efecto me trae el último registro insertado, pero me trae toda la información, por mas que en el `select` le digo que solo quiero el campo `'num_guia_despacho'`.

¿De qué manera puedo traer solo ese campo usando `latest()`?

Comment: En realidad para que te traiga solo el último registro deberías usar `first()` en vez de `get()`. Por lo demás, la consulta se ve bien.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ de hecho ni siquiera requiere `first` si solo quiere ese valor entonces haría mas sentido usar `value` y omitir get o first

Comment: @BetaM cierto, sería más eficiente de la manera que indicas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar `get` en estos casos no es lo adecuado, desde que este método te retornaría una colección.

Dado lo anterior y que solo planeas obtener el valor de una columna de un solo registro, entonces lo mas simple es usar al [método `value`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table) dejando así tu consulta:

```
$id_asignacion = AsignacionMaterial::latest()->value('num_guia_despacho');
```

Para profundizar mas en ello, te recomiendo revises a la clase **`Builder`** ubicada en: *vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder*